# How Remove permission denied with GRANT USAGE ON mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mail server in my ubuntu instance. I have a webserver management FROXLOR and i recieve errors for access denied when i try to login in mail account. The log for this:

```
Aug 16 03:14:33 email dovecot: auth-worker(15140): Error: mysql(127.0.0.1): Connect failed to database (froxlor): Access denied for user 'froxlor'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - waiting for 25 seconds before retry
Aug 16 03:14:58 email dovecot: auth-worker(15140): Error: mysql(127.0.0.1): Connect failed to database (froxlor): Access denied for user 'froxlor'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - waiting for 125 seconds before retry
```

I check in mysql and says this:

```
mysql> show grants for 'froxlor'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for froxlor@localhost                                                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'froxlor'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEE111112222333344444' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `froxlor`.* TO 'froxlor'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In google search, the line `GRANT USAGE on*.*`says the grant is related to NONE permissions.

I have tried to REVOKE permissions, DROP user, GRANT ALL with GRANT OPTION, and GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES and always with `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` and sometimes using `service mysql restart`.... but nothing solves this. Someone can help me? thanks in advance